# How to move positions of labels in a d3 dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I was able to add labels from a csv file with the code below, but the text from each row of the csv is on top of each other, do you know how to move it to look nicer?

```html
  svg.selectAll(".labels")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("text")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
              .attr("dy", ".70em")
              .text(function(d) { return d.TrackName; })
              .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a join on the data, you can access the `datum` as you've already demonstrated in your `attr` functions. However it also provides an `index` you can use as the 2nd parameter.

Change your

```
.attr("dy", ".70em")
```

to something more like this. What this does is multiples the 0.7 by the index of each item, producing a list of them. You may need to tweak the numbers depending on how it looks.

```
.attr("dy", (d, i) => `${i * 0.7}em`);
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks! That help a lot, and how would you move the entire labels to the left, right, up or down?

Comment: I mean, move to a position so that the labels are outside of the donut area.

Comment: If I add .attr("dy", (d, i) => `${i + 25.7}em`) as well, keeps going down but when it goes out of the donut area disappears